# Save the result of a dir command to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have tried running dir as echo to txt file but it just saves as a txt file with "dir" in it

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\comic\Desktop\CLI\Batch\logs\timestart
echo %username% Is running main.bat at %time% on %date% > log%date%.txt
echo Logging timestart to log.txt at %time% on %date%
cd C:\Users\comic\Desktop\CLI\Batch\logs\filelog
echo dir > log%date%.txt
exit
```

Comment: Change ```echo dir > log%date%.txt``` to ```dir 1>"log%date%.txt"```. However, it is unlikely that you will be able to use `%date%`, i.e. the expanded value date string, in a filename. The obvious reason  for me saying that is that there is a very large number of Windows PC's configured to use a date string containing characters considered invalid in Windows file or directory names.

Comment: Another way to do this is to put the re-direct in front like `>log%date%.txt dir`

Comment: Keep in mind you can use `>>` to append rather than overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are echoing the string `dir` to a file. If you want to save the command output to a file, you should use `dir > log%date%.txt`. You should also keep in mind that the `>` operation will overwrite the existing file. If you want to add on to the file, you can use the `>>` operation.